# Batch File Time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I add the time to this batch file when I rename the file?

The results look like this but need time also: `Daily Report_Wed 08222018.pdf`

```
@echo off
Pushd c:\Temp
pdftk *.pdf cat output %fn%.pdf
ren %fn%.pdf %fn%.xxx
del *.pdf
ren %fn%.xxx   "Daily Report".pdf
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do set today=%%a%%b%%c
for %%f in (*.pdf) do ren "%%f" "%%~nf_%today%%%~xf"
mkdir "Daily Reports for Review"
move *.pdf "Daily Reports for Review"
```

Comment: So what is stopping you from doing the same thing with the %time% variable?

Comment: As with your earlier question, you have an undefined variable, `%fn%`.

Comment: I'm new to this. Don't know how to add the %time%. That's why I'm here

Comment: You have code to split apart the date variable.  You don't think you can use the same concept to split apart the time variable?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that could get you close to what you want (I modified your 1<sup>st</sup> `for` loop):

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow>echo Date: [%date%], Time: [%time%]
> Date: [2018-08-22], Time: [22:51:36.23]
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow>for /f "tokens=1-6 delims=/-:., " %a in ('echo %date: =0%-%time: =0%') do (echo set now=%a%b%c%d%e%f)
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow>(echo set now=20180822225136 )
> set now=20180822225136
> ```

**Notes**:

- Since I am directly in *cmd* window, and you're in a *batch* file you have to double the percent sign (`%`) for parameters (`%a` -> `%%a`, `%b` -> `%%b`, ... like you already have in your snippet). For more details, check [[SS64]: Double %% symbols why are they needed in a batch file?](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html)
- As you probably noticed (most likely due to "*Regional settings*"), my date format differs than yours (that's why I added the *hyphen* (`-`) in the `delims` list; also the items ordering is reversed), so you might get slightly different behaviors on different computers (things will get even worse on non English locales, as @Stephan noticed), so it's not a reliable solution (I guess this is *batch* processing generic)

Comment: you should use `%time: =0%`. Note: does not work correctly with all localizations (in German, the time format is `21:26:14,43` - note the comma)

Comment: @Stephan: Thank you for your input. I did some small corrections, and also added some notes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested example for you which uses `WMIC` to retrieve non locale dependent date and time values:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Exist "C:\Temp\*.pdf" (CD /D "C:\Temp") Else Exit /B

Rem The values below can be modified according to your language or preferred day names
Set "WeekDays=Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday"

For /F %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get /Value^|FindStr "[0-9]$"') Do Set "%%A"
For /F "Tokens=1%DayOfWeek%" %%A In (". . . . . . . . . %WeekDays%") Do Set "DayName=%%A"
For %%A In (Day Hour Minute Month Second) Do Call Set "%%A=0%%%%A%%" & Call Set "%%A=%%%%A:~-2%%"

Rem Choose the output %FileName% you want from the following variables:
Rem %Year% e.g. 2018
Rem %Quarter% e.g. 3
Rem %Month% e.g. 08
Rem %WeekInMonth% e.g. 4
Rem %Day% e.g. 22
Rem %DayOfWeek% as an integer where Monday from %WeekDays% is 1 e.g. 3
Rem %DayName% as a string taken from %WeekDays% e.g. Wednesday
Rem %Hour% in 24 hr format e.g. 21
Rem %Minute% e.g. 57
Rem %Second% e.g. 53
Set "FileName=%DayName% %Month%%Day%%Year%%Hour%%Minute%%Second%"

Rem Choose the full or relative output directory name
Set "DirName=Daily Reports for Review"

If Not Exist "%DirName%\" MD "%DirName%"
PDFTK *.pdf cat output "%DirName%\%FileName%.pdf" && Del /Q *.pdf
```

You will need to include the full or relative path to `PDFTK` on the last line if it is not located in the current working directory, *(`C:\Temp`)*, or in `%PATH%`. Other than that, you should only make modifications to values on lines beginning with `Set`.

*Empty lines and those `Rem`arked can be optionally removed once you've made your modifications.*

Comment: For those who have not wmic.exe on its systems (home version of OS), getwmiproperty could be used instead: `getwmiproperty.exe -delimiter # -class Win32_LocalTime -property Hour,Minute,Second,day,month,year`

Comment: Link to sw used in previous comment http://glsft.free.fr/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=70&Itemid=28