# Batch files path warning message

Tags: batch-file

I wrote the script below to work in combination with pdftk. It will look in multiple directories and if there are any PDf's it will combine them, delete the originals and create a folder and move them to that folder. My question is: Is there a way that if one or more of the directories don't exist a warning message will be generated that the directory is missing?

```
@echo off
Pushd c:\Directory1
 pdftk *.pdf cat output %fn%.pdf
 ren %fn%.pdf %fn%.xxx
 del *.pdf
 ren %fn%.xxx   "Daily Report".pdf
 for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do set Date=%%a-%%b-%%c
 for %%f in (*.pdf) do ren "%%f" "%%~nf_%Date%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%%%~xf"
 mkdir "Daily Reports for Review"
 move *.pdf "Daily Reports for Review"

Pushd c:\Directory2
 pdftk *.pdf cat output %fn%.pdf
 ren %fn%.pdf %fn%.xxx
 del *.pdf
 ren %fn%.xxx   "Daily Report".pdf
 for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do set today=%%a-%%b-%%c
 for %%f in (*.pdf) do ren "%%f" "%%~nf_%Date%_%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%.%time:~6,2%%%~xf"
 mkdir "Daily Reports for Review"
 move *.pdf "Daily Reports for Review"
```

Comment: As I mentioned in comment to your previous question, you are still using an undefined variable, **`%fn%`**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer, as did my last one in your previous question, *(which remains unresolved)*, assumes that you are merging all `.pdf`s in each directory to a single output file. In this case the output file would be named `Daily Report_mm-DD-YYYY_HH.MM.SS.pdf` and be written into a relative directory named `Daily Reports For Review`.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "DS="
For /F "Tokens=1-6 Delims=/: " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined DS Set "DS=%%B-%%C-%%A_%%D.%%E.%%F"
If Not Defined DS Exit /B
Set "DN=Daily Reports for Review"
Set "FN=Daily Report"
For %%A In ("C:\Directory1" "C:\Directory2") Do If Not Exist "%%~A\" (
    Echo %%~A does not exist) Else (
    If Not Exist "%%~A\*.pdf" (Echo No PDF's in %%A) Else Call :Sub "%%~A")
Pause 
Exit /B

:Sub
PushD %1
If Not Exist "%DN%\" MD "%DN%"
PDFTk *.pdf cat output "%DN%\%FN%_%DS%.pdf" && Del /Q *.pdf
PopD
Exit /B
```

*If you are not writing all `.pdf`'s in each directory to a single output file, you need to explain what you are doing because this is your third question about the same task and you have not explained that task adequately*.

---

**Courtesy Edit**
You can use `WMIC` to generate your DateStamp if you want to include the day of week name as part of the string.

To do so, replace lines `3` and `4` in the script above with:

```bat
Set "WeekDays=Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat"
For /F %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get /Value^|FindStr "[0-9]$"') Do Set "%%A"
For /F "Tokens=1%DayOfWeek%" %%A In (". . . . . . . . . %WeekDays%") Do Set "DayName=%%A"
For %%A In (Day Hour Minute Month Second) Do Call Set "%%A=0%%%%A%%" & Call Set "%%A=%%%%A:~-2%%"
Set "DS=%DayName%_%Month%-%Day%-%Year%_%Hour%.%Minute%.%Second%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponce. Actually I want to merge only what is in each directory into it own folder called “ Daily reports to review” in that directory.

Comment: Did you try the code? Is that not what it is doing? If in doubt, add an `Echo` at the start of line `16`, `Echo PDFTk ...`, _it'll print what it would do instead of actually doing it_.

Comment: Works great. The only issue is that if there are no pdf's in the directory I am getting this message. Error: Unable to find file Error: Failed to open pdf files. Error encountered: No output created. Is there anyway of not displaying these messages? There are going to be 30 directories that may not have pdf's in the daily report,

Comment: @JohnMolina, I've made a simple `If`/`Else` modification to prevent directories without PDF's from being passed to the PDFTk sub-section. _Please also revisit you previous question I answered and check that my similar answer resolved it too!_

Comment: another possibility is to [redirect](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) the errors to NUL with `2>nul`

Comment: It's better. Now it only says "No PDF's in "C:\Directory1".

Comment: No problem, BTW, if you don't want to know about non existing directories or those without `.pdf`'s you can replace the `3` line `For` loop with `For %%A In ("C:\Directory1" "C:\Directory2") Do If Exist "%%~A\*.pdf" Call :Sub "%%~A"`.

Comment: One  last thing. How do I add the day of the week to the Pdf name. example Mon_08-27-2018_08.11.03?

Comment: `RoboCopy`, does not determine the day of week name; to do that I'd suggest you use the `WMIC` method, [I gave you in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51975187) to the last question you asked, _and which still remains unresolved_. I have as a courtesy, added that method to my answer with instruction in how to make the change yourself.